# Check if a radio button exists with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a certain `radio` button exists with jQuery, I have this below:

```
if (jQuery('input[name=list_in]', '#sell_form').length) {
    return true;
}
```

This works, but it will return even if the field is not a radio field. I need it to return true ONLY if the field is named `list_in` *and* is a `radio` field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if (jQuery('input[type=radio][name=list_in]', '#sell_form').length) {
   return true;
}
```

From [:radio](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) Selector docs:

> Because **:radio** is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :radio cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM *querySelectorAll()*
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use **[type="radio"]**
>   instead.

Comment: Oh ok, so you can just add any attributes in that fashion?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector

```
if (jQuery(':radio[name=list_in]', '#sell_form').length) {
```

Comment: `checkbox` not `checkboc`

Comment: checkbox? Do you mean `:radio`? :)