# How to check if a radio button exists using jquery and avoid jquery to stack

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I have a simple jQuery function that checks if a radio button exists. I want my code to do the following:

If the radio button element exists then check which one is selected. If none is selected then the variable type that i use in my code should be empty, otherwise it should have the selected radio button's value. In case the radio button does not exist at all, my function should show an alert message. The problem is that if the element does not exist then the jquery is not executed due to this line:

```
var type = $('input[name=type]:checked').val());
```

Since it seems jquery does not run if you have a line of code that uses an element that does not exist, is there a way to avoid this and allow my code to work wither the radio button exists or not?

```
if (jQuery('input[type=radio][name=type]').length) {
    var type = $('input[name=type]:checked').val());
    if (!type) { 
        var type = '';
    }
} else {
    alert ('element does not exist');
}
```

Thank you in advance.
P.S. Without the line in question the code is executed normaly.

Comment: You have an extraneous `)` at the end of the line. Removing that will probably fix it. If your analysis of the problem was correct, the solution would be to *look before you leap*. Eg. `if ($('input[name=type]:checked').val()) { ... }`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697161/check-if-a-radio-button-exists-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523432/check-if-radio-button-exists-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `)` in :

```
var type = $('input[name=type]:checked').val());
______________________________________________^
```

Hope this helps.